# Should I put my car in first when parked?

Tags: manual-transmission, shifting, parking

When I park my car and turn it off, I usually select first gear, pull the parking brake, kill the engine, and then release the clutch pedal. I did this because I thought it would keep the car from rolling when parked, in case the parking brake somehow failed.

However, I have recently read on multiple forums that you should leave the car in neutral when you park. Is there any danger of leaving the car in first while parked? While it damage the car? Should it be in neutral?

Comment: I've always done it the way you describe; I'm interested to hear what others have to say.

Comment: I always put it in Reverse. No issue with leaving it in gear when parked.Why reverse?, it is a low gear ratio and is harder for the car to roll since it has to turn the engine more revolutions per foot of roll which makes it harder to roll than first gear.

Comment: @moab I have just looked up a few mass produced car gear ratios and the majority have a 1st gear with a slightly higher ratio than reverse.

Comment: @HandyHowie thanks for checking that, it was not that way with 4 speed trannys, Im getting old...old habits die hard! How is it across the pond?